# check for exact sub string in a line

Tags: perl

I am trying to check for a exact substring `tool` in a line.
Where i am trying below reg-ex to achieve the same.

```
my $line = "test git_toolk_test is git";
if ($line =~ m/(\w)*tool(\w)*/){
        print "============MATCH=======\n";
    }
```

It matches the `toolk`. But in this case, i am just looking to match exact string `tool`. If sub string `tool` is present in my string, Then my `if` check should hit.

My above code works if i assign $line to values like :- `hai_git_tool` , `tool_test_log`.

But it also works for values like `toolk_test_log` , `hai_git_toolget`  Which is not expected. Am i missing something in pattern math expression?

i also try to match other way  of having my `if` check :- `[^a-zA-z]tool[^a-zA-Z]`, It's not working when string starts/ends with string `tool`

Please help!

Comment: Perhaps you should add some test cases to specify what it is exactly that you are after. Output and expected output. Your previous question that was identical to this one was closed, just reposting the exact same question is not likely to get you a better answer.

Comment: Why don't you use the string comparison operator `eq` instead of a regular expression if you want an exact match? Or do you mean you want to match on word boundaries? In that case, enclose the search term in `\b`: `\btool\b`?

Comment: @Robert `\b` does not trigger for underscore.

Comment: Perhaps what you after is `print '--- Match ---' if $line =~ /\Wtool\W/;`.

Comment: @PolarBear Underscore is included in `\w`, so it will not be matched by `\W`.

Comment: @TLP, I have updated my query. Please check! Hope that helps.

Comment: @kathy `A-z` is wrong, but I assume that is a typo. You still have not added any test cases, which is pretty important in a case such as this. Especially since you have not really formulated any rule for the match, except "exact match". Also, since you have waited 2 days to respond, this question is now fairly inactive.

Comment: You probably want something like `(?<![A-Za-z_])tool(?![A-Za-z_])`, where you use negative lookaround assertions to make sure the word does not extend forwards or backwards. This works also for start/end of string. Include all legal word characters in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just looking to match exact string `tool`

From your examples I assume you want to match

- `tool` at the beginning of the line followed by a non alphabetic character, or
- `tool` at the end of the line preceded by a non alphabetic character, or
- `tool` preceded by and followed by a non alphabetic character

Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
my @test_cases = ("test git_toolk_test is git",
                  "hai_git_tool", "a tool_test_log",
                  "toolk_test_log", "hai_git_toolget",
                  '${tool-install_dir}/6.4.0-2');
for my $line (@test_cases) {
    say "$line";
    if ($line =~ m/(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])tool(?:$|[^a-zA-Z])/){
        say "  --> MATCH";
    }
    else {
        say "  --> NO MATCH";
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
test git_toolk_test is git
  --> NO MATCH
hai_git_tool
  --> MATCH
a tool_test_log
  --> MATCH
toolk_test_log
  --> NO MATCH
hai_git_toolget
  --> NO MATCH
${tool-install_dir}/6.4.0-2
  --> MATCH
```

Comment: Hi Hakon, It might not always `tool_` , `_tool_` , String might also have any special characters other than '_'. eg string:- `${tool-install_dir}/5.7` where `tool`  exists in sting, and i want to hit `if` condition.

Comment: @kathy I have updated my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: No, I am using this string `${tool_install_dir}/6.4.0-2` to match against your expression.

Comment: @kathy It works for me with `${tool_install_dir}/6.4.0-2`

Comment: Sorry there was typo while pasting your check while testing. It worked for me.Thanks! Could you help me what is mean by `?:^` and `?:$` here?

Comment: @kathy They are explained in [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut). The first one `^` matches the beginning of a line, the second one `$`, matches the end of the line. `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

bYou can just use,

```perl
if ( $line =~ /(?:\b|_)tool(?:\b|_)/ )
```

`\b` is documented as

> One such sequence is `\b`, which matches a boundary of some sort. `\b{wb}` and a few others give specialized types of boundaries. (They are all described in detail starting at `\b{}`, `\b`, `\B{}`, `\B` in `perlrebackslash`.) Note that these don't match characters, but the zero-width spaces between characters.

Note that `_` is in `\w` so you want to match either a boundary or a `_`.

Comment: String might also have other special chars other than `_`.